# Статичный элемент кирпичной сетки с помощью Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть подгружаемые картинки/гифки разной высоты, которые случайным образом располагаются по сетке Masonry. Но один элемент всегда должен находится на одном и том же элементе. То есть, как на giphy.com: блок Trending TV всегда находится на своем месте, независимо от других блоков. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: На giphy.com они сделали совершенно интересно. Вместо того что бы вклинивать элемент в сетку они просто сделали отступы `padding-top: 304px;` для двух центральных столбиков. Довольно креативно, а вам советую заглядывать в исходный код и приводить пример кода/мыслей на тему вопроса.

Comment: Я знаю, что в giphy это сделано другим способом, но мне интересно, можно ли сделать такое с помощью библиотеки Masonry